# Add feature to replica

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, replication

I create one-way replica from one  geodatabase to another. After that, i add new feature class in parent geodatabase.
Is it possible to include new feature class in replica, but i don't want to recreate replica?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no out-of-the-box tool to add a feature class to an existing replica. Please see this [Esri KB article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35679):

> With ArcGIS Desktop, one must either recreate the replica or if the
>   workflow allows, replicate the new feature class as a separate
>   replica.

The only "core platform" way to do this is to use ArcObjects and there is a [sample](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/da79f58c-971a-454e-bc52-974c2c47e26a.htm) and [another one](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000043w000000) for this (folks reported that they work, but have not tested on my own). More information on allowed schema changes and how to handle them in replicas is available from the [ArcGIS Help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000t2000000).

Other alternative is to use this [custom GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geodatabase/details?entryID=56ECA068-1422-2418-A093-2245A8401C16) that states that it makes it possible to add a feature class to a replica and then sync the changes. The tool was written for 10.0.

There is also an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008C8m&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Geodatabase&sort=comments) which you can vote for if you want to move this kind of functionality to the core.

Comment: I tried the custom GP tool and it doesn't work in 10.1. I'd really like this functionality as well, but I have no idea how to even start with ArcObjects....